# may i inflate two list layout in one RecycleView Adapter?

Tags: java, android

what I am trying to do? I have one SQLite data table and from that data table, I want to show a different column to the different activities. for that, I use recycle view and for that recycle view I create two model list view layout. then create one RecylerView Adapter. In **onCreateViewHolder** method, I want to inflate the two model list view layout.
[here is the code what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeWiw.png)

Comment: Please, add your code to your question, avoid putting external links to images of it, it's much more practical to use the proper code formatting features already present on the editor

Answer (score 0):

you can try following recyclerview multipleview type you host two layouts in one adapter class

[recyclerview multipleviewtype](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example#android-recyclerview-multiple-viewtype-project-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

thanks to the `getItemViewType` method you can return different values for `view type` that can be caught at `onCreateViewHolder` and depend on the value you can inflate different layout.

I was enabled to create one adapter for chat messages whether is sent or received `text/image` I inflate different layouts depend on `view typeviewType`

code for specified `viewType` value

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    /**
     * check the user id to detect if a message sent or received
     * then check if a message is a text or image
     */

    String userID = Constant.itemUser.getId();
    MessageModel message = messages.get(position);

    if (userID.equals(message.getUserId())) {

        if (message.getType().equals("1")) {
            return MessageType.SENT_TEXT;
        } else if (message.getType().equals("2")) {
            return MessageType.SENT_IMAGE;
        }

    } else {

        if (message.getType().equals("1")) {
            return MessageType.RECEIVED_TEXT;
        } else if (message.getType().equals("2")) {
            return MessageType.RECEIVED_IMAGE;
        }

    }
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

and in a method named `onCreateViewHolder`

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    /**
     * check the type of view and return holder
     */
    if (viewType == MessageType.SENT_TEXT) {
        return new SentTextHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_message_text, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == MessageType.SENT_IMAGE) {
        return new SentImageHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_message_img, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == MessageType.RECEIVED_TEXT) {
        return new ReceivedTextHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_text, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == MessageType.RECEIVED_IMAGE) {
        return new ReceivedImageHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_img, parent, false));
    }

    return null;
}
```

please don't forget to handle `holders` in `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder mHolder, int position) {

    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    MessageModel message = messages.get(position);
    /**
     * check message type and init holder to user it and set data in the right place for every view
     */
    if (type == MessageType.SENT_TEXT) {
       // case of message sent of type text
    } else if (type == MessageType.SENT_IMAGE) {
       // case of message sent of type img
    } else if (type == MessageType.RECEIVED_TEXT) {
        ReceivedTextHolder holder = (ReceivedTextHolder) mHolder;
        // case of the message received of type text

    } else if (type == MessageType.RECEIVED_IMAGE) {
        // etc
    }

}
```